# SQLite.NET causes reappearing and inconsistent problems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a project for my company which I'm leading. At some point it was a requirement that the client-side storage should be a SQLite DB to be complaint with older databases. That's irrelevant tho. My solution was using the SQLite.NET package from NuGET with EntityFramework and CodeFirst to automate the process or creating and managing a DB file. After 1 day of tinkering with it i finally got it to work. But then of course my colleague updates from the SVN and his consoles suddenly shows 200+ errors related to SQLite and 3 on the assemblies wont compile because despite the fact that there is no compiler errors.

I did find the solution in this case which included perpetually running around the office and fixing all the other guys problems. My checklist was like so:

- Is all the projects set to **.net 4.0**?
- Is **Bcl.Async** Installed?
- Is **SQLite** Installed?

If either of these points were missing the project would not be able to reference some of the other assemblies and the compiler would just come up with an error "*Unable to resolve reference/dependency*" or something. No red lines in the text editor and F12(Go to definition) is working as it should. **But i can't compile it.**

Also randomly the project seems to fail between each of the other developers. I just tell them to install/reinstall SQLite through the NuGET and most the times it works.

Last time the SQLite updated from 1.0.98 -> 1.0.99 and NuGET picked up the latest version causing a conflict in versions in all the other projects and i spend 2 days fixing it since all the other projects were forced to reference SQLite too. Invalidating latter approach. What's gonna happen next time they roll out a new version?

Anyways a magical problem like many:

[image: Project setup]

The *ChatService* which is in this case is the project i want to reference from my *UnitTest* project. The *Lib* project is the one which contains the SQLite setup. When i boot up the system from the *BaseFrame* project there is NO problems. But when i start it through the UnitTest project, heck even if i create a new project and try to call a linq function in SQlite EF i get this:

[image: Magical new error]

My suspicion is that it has something to do with a clusterfuck of versions or a threading problem. Reality is; i have no idea why.

I suspect the threading problem because of a different error i got last year. Look at this: (Which is still unresovled)
[image: Execution path]
Error:
[image: Another mystery error]

The same function failing in different contexts. What is this  madness?

Wow you made it this far? Or did you just skip along ;) Anyways. To summarize the questions It's:

- If i reference a project that uses SQLite, that referring project must also reference SQLite. Why? And can it be avoided?
- Why is CodeFirst failing in one project but not the other?
- Why is it that when i call the CreateDb(); function through a button click event the creation will fail?
- Why is SQLite so hard to work with? Should i use something else?

Thanks.